# Rendering only component template in router-outlet in Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm having troubles using Angular router-oulet because it adds new elements to the DOM and it affects the CSS rules that are applied because it breaks the parent-child relationship of some elements. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: Code sample]

As you can see, after each `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is the inserted component selector (`app-fwc-dashboard-main` and `app-fwc-policy-main` in the code) and all the component template markup comes underneath it. This makes that there are some CSS rules that are not applied and the layout is broken.

I've been comparing the code from one version to the other and I've realized that the component selector has the class `ng-star-inserted` so I've tried to add the missing CSS rules, like this:

```
.grid-y > .ng-star-inserted > .auto, .grid-y > .ng-star-inserted > .shrink {
  height: auto;
}

.grid-y > .ng-star-inserted > .cell {
  width: auto;
}

(etc)
```

But, for some reason I can't find, it didn't work. So my question is: Is there any way to tell Angular router outlet to inject ONLY the component template markup and avoid adding the selector?

Or is there any other suggestion for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

As I see it you have two possible solutions:

- Remove the `>` selectors in your css.
- Include the component selector in your css.

If these doesn't work for you I suggest rewriting the code in a manner which makes it easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector for Component.
Add classes using `@HostBinding` and css selector `:host` inside styles.

```
@Component({
   selector: '[attributeSelector]',
   template: 'red text',
   styles: [':host {color: red}'],
})
class A {
   @HostBinding('class') class = 'boundClass';
}
```

In this case `router-outlet` will create something like

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div attributeSelector class="boundClass" nghost_1>red text</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll do some tests with it.

Comment: Just tested, you can specify the element: `selector: '<section [component-tag]>'`

Answer (score 0):

Ilia Volk's answer showed me the right track to find the solution. I changed the component selector to this:

```
selector: '[app-vpn-component].grid-y.medium-grid-frame',
```

This way, the rendered markup is:

```
<div app-fwc-vpn-main="" class="grid-y medium-grid-frame ng-star-inserted">
  ...
</div>
```

And now the layout looks as before.